# How to test express GET request?

Tags: javascript, express, testing, jestjs

I have an endpoint in `ExpressJS` which return me an array of elements, but only this elements where type is this same as type in request query params, here is code,

the endpoint return this array:

```
[
    {
        "type":[1,2]
    }
]
```

GET request looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/types?type=1&type=2
```

how to test this endpoint? I need to check if my function return me objects where `type` array contain `type` from request query, i try like this:

```
describe('getTypes()', () => {
    it('It should return only objects contains 1 as a type', async () => {
        const res = await request(app)
            .get('/api/types?type=1')

        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    })
})
```

but i do not know what to do now, can someobody tell me how to test it?

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can grab the body from the response and expect that it is whatever you expect it to be. That said, I don't understand the logic. Where are 3 and 4 coming from?

Comment: This is only example, I remove 3 and 4, I do not know what response looks like so I can't grab it and expect to it

Comment: If you don't know what the response looks like, it seems like you can't test it other than asserting that it exists and that the status code is as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) HTTP assertion library.

Using this library you could then test your endpoint as follows:

```
imprt request from 'supertest';

describe('getTypes', () => {
    it('should return only type 1 objects', (done) => {
        request(app)
            .get('/api/types?type=1')
            .expect(200)
            .then(response => {
              expect(response.body[0].type).toBe([1]);
              done();
             })
            .catch(err => done(err))
    });
});
```